# VB.NET Get Process list and kill process

Tags: vb.net, process

i want to insert all processes that running into listbox,

and also how to "kill" process and start process?

```
for i = 0 to procCount
...
next i
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the list + kill:

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
    ListBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName.ToString)
    If String.compare(p.ProcessName, "iexplore",true) = 0 Then
        p.Kill()
    End If
Next
```

use the `kill()` to kill process
to open process:

```
Process.Start("pname.exe")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a list with all running processes of Excel before starting Excel programatically (using Linq statement):

```
Dim lstExcelProcess As List(Of Process) = (From p As Process In Process.GetProcesses Where p.ProcessName.ToUpper Like "Excel*".ToUpper).ToList
```

And after you finished what you had to do, kill the only process that was not listed before:

```
Dim process As Process = (From p As Process In process.GetProcesses Where p.ProcessName.ToUpper Like "Excel*".ToUpper And Not lstExcelProcess.Contains(p))(0)
            process.Kill()
```