# How to allow code to run only if a window with specific window title does not exist?

Tags: vb.net

I have program that acts as a GUI frontend for a CLI program.  I can set custom titles for the CMD windows that open (up to 4), but  despite looking at other answers to similar questions, I can't piece together the code to check through the array for the specific window titles.  Could someone help me out with an example?

EDIT: Including other questions.

[how to get the window title of a process using vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131303/how-to-get-the-window-title-of-a-process-using-vb-net)

[VB.NET Get Process list and kill process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100732/vb-net-get-process-list-and-kill-process)

Comment: Could you please link to the answers and similar questions?

Comment: Why not make your app *start* the CLI app; you could get the process handle when you do.

Comment: @Plutonix - the GUI app does start the CLI app (Livestreamer), how do I grab the PID when that starts?

Comment: Do you use [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=PT-BR&k=k%28System.Diagnostics.Process.Start%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true) to run your app? It returns a [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object with the info you'd need.

Comment: No, I use `Shell()` because I have to pass arguments for stuff.  The CMD windows all have specific window titles though, so I shouldn't need to use `Process.Start()`.

Comment: It is 2016, use Process.Start - it is perfectly capable of handling commandline args

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple answer - you can use `AppActivate()` and checking the error numbers to check if the window title exists.